# [Micronaut]: No reactive transaction management has been configured. Ensure you have correctly configured a reactive capable transaction manager

Tags: postgresql, micronaut-data

I have a set of dependencies for Postgres and Micronaut, as shown below:

```
implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql")
implementation(libs.micronaut.data.jdbc)
annotationProcessor(libs.micronaut.data.processor)
implementation(libs.micronaut.jdbc.hikari)
implementation(libs.javax.inject)
implementation(libs.micronaut.data.r2dbc)
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Yes as there is r2dbc so you need to configure reactive tx manager

Comment: Use jpa with r2dbc your issue will be resolved and if you want jdbc then need some more configuration.